# Mapping backbone events in a separate backbone class file

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using CoffeeScript with a Backbone view class. When I include the class in the same page as the html everything works fine. When I use a separate file and export the class, it initialises but the events aren't mapped.

The class file is:

```
root = exports ? this

class root.AppView extends Backbone.View

    el: $("#app")

    events:
        'click #appBtn1' : 'handleEvent'
        'click #appBtn2' : 'handleEvent'

    initialize: =>
        alert 'init'

    handleEvent: =>
        alert 'event'
```

Only the initialize function fires. What do I need to alter to map the events when the code is in a separate class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the function

```
$("#app")
```

runs immediately when you define the class. So when the class is in a separate file, the `#app` element doesn't (necessarily) exist in the DOM yet.

What you should be doing is using a selector string instead, which Backbone will pass to the `$` function when the class is instantiated:

```
el: "#app"
```